# Searching a boost::bimap for the current class instance

Tags: c++, boost, bimap

Ok, so I a boost::bimap declared as so:

```
boost::bimap<object*, position> object_list;
```

Where object and position are a class and a struct, respectively.

Within the current object stored in the bimap, I want to find its own entry.

I am currently trying to do so like this:

```
void order::do_thing() {
    ...
    position pos = object_list.left.at(this);
    ...
}
```

I have trouble parsing the error output, but it seems like the at function of the bimap doesn't like the const-ness and/or reference-ness of this (and yes, I know this is an rvalue).

What would be the proper/suggested way to do this search?

Here is a snippet of the error:

```
order.cpp:117:56:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bimap/container_adaptor/associative_container_adaptor.hpp:207:56: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::bimaps::container_adaptor::detail::key_to_base_identity<object*, object* const>) (order* const&)’
                 this->template functor<key_to_base>()(k)
```

---

(Edit added to address sehe's comments and to point out the problem)

Apologies if my post was in bad etiquette, I am both new to posting on SO and I was under the assumption that just dumping all of my code (just to include the custom objects and templates for this section of code is hundreds of lines) would be considered bad form, so I trimmed it down to (what I thought was) the bare minimum to still get the issue.

And just to address the test-cases link, I do write test cases. In this case I was swapping out a vector for a bimap to add in the position code, and this actually fails to compile (though I will say I was not very explicit on it being a compilation error, and not a stack trace). I'm assuming you (sehe), thought I was talking about a runtime error, because otherwise I don't see how the link was relevant.

Anyway, I was trimming out code down to the actual minimum to reproduce the error so I could post it here, and then realized the actual issue. As shown above, the bimap holds values `<`**object***`, position>` But the class trying to insert itself into the bimap is an *order* class: `void`**order**`::do_thing() {`

So it turned out to be a simple type error. Sorry, everyone, for asking a really dumb question. I guess that is what I get for working on projects at 3 AM.

Comment: You should show your actual code. By spending time I was able to /guess/ your likely problem, but if you had included a SSCCE and the actual compiler messages, you would have saved yourself (and others) a lot of time.

Comment: See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem.

The only pitfall I can think of is that you have `this` implicitly const. In that case, the map will have to take pointers to  `const object` instead!

See this sample here. Uncomment `// const` to see the variation with const:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14366cc0ad290b2d)</kbd>** (non-const)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49318817eaf7e116)</kbd>** (const)

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using position = std::string;

#define USE_CONST // const

struct object {
    template <typename BiMap>
    position get_position(BiMap const& bimap) USE_CONST {
        return bimap.left.at(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<object> instances(10);

    boost::bimap<object USE_CONST*, position> mapping;

    for (auto& instance : instances)
        mapping.insert({&instance, "instance #" + std::to_string(mapping.size()+1)});

    for (auto& instance : instances)
        std::cout << "Instance reports " << instance.get_position(mapping) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Instance reports instance #1
Instance reports instance #2
Instance reports instance #3
Instance reports instance #4
Instance reports instance #5
Instance reports instance #6
Instance reports instance #7
Instance reports instance #8
Instance reports instance #9
Instance reports instance #10
```

Comment: Not technically the issue, and I think your links were a little over the top, but pairing down the code to be postable here led me to see the issue, so I'll give you the answer credit.